# Upgrade 18.04 to 20.04 hangs after "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration"

Tags: upgrade, lvm

These are the last lines I see. There does not seem to be an error message, but after 20 minutes the picture is the same. When I interrupt the update and restart the laptop I receive a kernel panic. Luckily, by booting into a live system and merging the lvm snapshot I am back at a working 18.04 setup.

What could be the problem?[image]
Sorry for the image.

This is on a slimbook X15, encrypted lvm setup on an nvme ssd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact details to answer: "What could be the problem?", but I did get around this problem (i.e. I did manage to upgrade to 20.04, while using lvm2 after receiving the "leaked on vgs invocation" error/warning messages).

I believe it's because you are using logical volumes, and possibly (as I was) using an lvm snapshot during the upgrade. After my upgrade stopped at this point I waited ages before realizing dpkg wasn't going to do anything else.

I wouldn't recommend this unless you are desperate to upgrade - it could go horribly wrong... I made sure I had a recent 'dd' full disk backup, then killed all dpkg processes (that had been doing nothing for a hour or so), there were two of them showing with `ps aux`: the one I expected and also a memtest86+ one. Then I followed some web instructions (am I allowed to reference them here?):

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I made a point of looking for any errors on the terminal near where the "initramfs" statements are printed.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` didn't find any problems, and so didn't try to fix any, so I rebooted, and 20.04 was running fine. I've since deleted the snapshot (i.e. kept the upgrade to 20.04, and not reverted to the earlier ubuntu release)

Comment: I am indeed using a snapshot during the upgrade (and considering how the upgrade went, I am glad I did). I am going to try your suggestion, though probably after the release of 20.04.01.

Comment: and yes, you are allowed to reference external sources as long as you repeat the steps you took here. (I am not sure if there is a reputation threshold for this though)

Comment: Related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/1876506 Your solution worked, though it is important to note that the processess should be killed from another terminal so as to allow the installer to continue its work